# Incrementing pointer location

Tags: c, pointers, increment

I have a character pointer that I use for part of the file name of a CSV file.  I need to have it follow the following pattern: 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, A, B, ..., Y, Z, 10, 11, ... etc. forever. The following code is the part of the program that handles that but I get a segmentation fault when I try to increment one of the "digits" in the character pointer `FILE_num`. I'm pretty sure what I have there now increments the pointer to the next address (which doesn't exist).

I've tried a number of things that just do not work (half of which do the same thing and the other half don't compile). It could be something else that's failing but I'm fairly sure that's it. I have to use C so I can't use strings, unfortunately.

```
char * FILE_num ;

//
// from earlier in the program
//

FILE_num = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char)) ;
FILE_num = "0" ;

//
// skip several things that work but do not relate (maybe)
//

int lines = 0 ,
    digit     ;

//
// some code that counts lines in a file
//

if (lines > 0xfffff) { // if file is too large start new file
    for (digit = strlen (FILE_num) ; digit >= 0 ; digit --) {
        if (FILE_num [digit] == 'Z') { // add to proper digit
            FILE_num [digit] = '0' ;
                    }
        else if (FILE_num [digit] == '9') { // skip :;<=>?@
            FILE_num [digit] = 'A' ;
            break ;
        }
        else {
            FILE_num [digit] ++ ; // segmentation fault here
            break ;
        }
    }
    //
    // Some other code to handle overflow of digits
    //
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have memory leak and undefined behavior.

```
FILE_num = "0" ;
```

Causing the memory leak - lost the address of the dynamicallly allocated memory.

"0" is an array which contains the characters `'0'` and `\0`. When you write this statement - that array decays into pointer to the first element of the array and then you assign it. `FILE_num` earlier contained the address of the allocated memory. Now you don't have that (***as per your given code*** - if you didn't store the address somewhere else.). So you can't access it. That's why it is a memory leak.

String literals in C are immutable. You trying to change it. Which is undefined behavior.

And again,

```
FILE_num = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char)) ;
```

is allocating memory for `1` `char`. You should allocate memory of appropriate size. If it is of size `1` that you want to allocate then you would better use `char` only (which is not the case here).

```
digit = strlen (FILE_num);...
```

Here you are accessing the `\0` first - which is not needed. You can loop over from `strlen( FILE_NUM )-1` to `0`.

And also the `malloc`'s returned `void*` is converted to `char*` implicitly - you don't need to cast it.

So the correct way would be to

```
FILE_num = malloc (sizeof (char) * LENGTH) ;
```

You need to check the return value of `malloc` so that in case it fails you will handle that situation.

```
if( NULL == FILE_num ){
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also your idea of skipping `skip :;<=>?@` is not that clear. You might want to recheck the logic properly.

---

```
FILE_num = malloc(..)
char *store_for_later_use = FILE_num;
...
```

Now you can change `FILE_num`.

If you want to initialize `FILE_num` with a string that has the same content as `"0"` use `strdup` (In case of its absence (not part of standard), you can copy it (`"0"`) to a dynamicaly allocated memory).

```
FIL_num = strdup("0");
```

Note free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it. 
(You need to free the address of the memory that `strdup` returned also).

Comment: I'm a little confused by the memory leak part; if you could elaborate further it'd be much appreciated. For example, how does it lose the address?

Comment: Also after the loop shown, I use realloc() to make it the size I need it if necessary; I just left it out. I'll change how I handle malloc() too, thanks

Comment: Hmm ok, thank you. How should I handle it so it doesn't decay? Or how can I store the address for later use (or am I completely not understanding this properly)?

Comment: strdup() fixed it; thanks, man. As for the skipping ":;<=>?@", in ASCII, those characters are in between '9' and 'A' so I have to jump past them if I'm at '9'. Did I do that incorrectly?

Comment: @xYouman.: With this context informtion - yes it is clear. You are doing it right.

Comment: So apparently I lose the memory again (possibly) after I increment the digit.  I get "2" immediately after but when the program tries to use it later it is blank or empty or something. What could cause that?

Comment: @xYouman.: No you won't lose any memory. You just change the content of it. Earlier you got seg fault here because you were trying to modify somehtng that isn;t modifiable. Everything else is fine

Comment: So it's not a memory loss but I'm still losing it after I exit the function this takes place in.  What could cause this? Should I show you more code or start a new question entirely? I'm at a loss.

Comment: @xYouman.: Ask a new question - it would be better. It is discouraged to edit the question after answer specifying the problems in current ocde is being posted.

Comment: I can't make a new question for two days because people have downvoted this one... Did I format my question wrong or something? I don't understand how an honest question about not understanding something gets downvoted. Maybe you can enlighten me.

Comment: Maybe the question is too broad. You can do one thing - try to check the code, minimize the problems and compiler with all warnings enabled. Then try to solve every error/earning. 2 days later you can ask a good question. You will do fine.

Comment: I've been using -Wall the whole time. It doesn't give me any warnings which is why I came here after a few days trying to figure out that one issue. The reason my question is broad is that I simply had no idea what I was dealing with. Oh well, I'll try my best. Thanks for all your help.